# Navigate Mediawiki category pages through a dropdownbox on wiki page

Tags: mediawiki, dropdownbox, mediawiki-extensions, semantic-mediawiki

I have hundreds of pages in the same category and I need a way to add a navigation "form" (or equivalent) on top of every page inside that category using a dropdownbox. I can't use Extensions **categorytree** or **Tree and Menu**, for what I know, because their presentation is to big. Even a collapsed clickable tree expands and pushing the actual page to far down.

I have the extensions **Semantic MediaWiki** and **DynamicPageList** among other extensions. A list of links to pages inside category "**Test**" is easily added to a page using the following syntax:

```
{{#dpl:category=Test|format=,*,[[%PAGE%]]\n,}}
```

The result looks something like this (with clickable links):

- Test Semantic Maps
- Semantic tests
- Test forms
- Other tests
- Testing semantic navigation

The presentation is to big for me when the amount of pages exceeds 100. Is there any way to add the list of page link to a dropdownbox and if neccessary combine it with a "Navigate to"-button and paste that to a page?

I have investigated the possibility using a Semantic Form but dont understand how I can paste the Form to a page.

What I want is what in plain HTML looks like this:

```
<select>
 <option>Milk</option>
 <option>Coffee</option>
 <option>Tea</option>
</select>
```

I need it to enable the user to quickly browse to any of the pages inside a Category. The current page inside the Category should be "Default" so that it **is easy to find the previous and next page from the dropdown.**

Comment: That's a simple but quite specific need, so I would believe that the easiest way for you would be to write [that extension yourself](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Developing_extensions).

Comment: Thanks leo, perhaps that is the best option

Comment: Have you find something?

Answer (score 1):

I realize this was a long time ago - but I didn't see anything on MediaWiki.  I created [CategoryDropdown](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CategoryDropdown).  I'm not certain it meets your exact needs, but possibly.  It is currently listed as 'beta'. We'll see if it survives the review process.